# React Redux - storing logged in user details

Tags: reactjs, redux

Im confused in the best place to store logged in user details in a React / Redux application so that I would have access to the likes of first name and last name in the header on every route.

I have the user api key (JWT) stored in localStorage, but I see it is bad practice to store the likes of first name, last name, email etc in localStorage, due to XSS vulnerabilities.

I would prefer not to hit an API on every route just to return the same user details.

I tried storing them in a redux store as session.user, which gets unset when I do a page refresh or change the URL manually. (store is maintained when changing the route via redux saga `push`)

How can I store first name, last name etc to be used across multiple routes and on page refresh?

Comment: if you're just storing a JWT and only using that JWT to authenticate API calls, you should consider storing it as an httpOnly cookie instead of handling it with redux.

Answer (score 3):

My advice is when a user logs into your website, create a session identifier for them and store it in a cryptographically signed cookie. Make sure that whatever cookie library your web framework uses is setting the httpOnly cookie flag. This flag makes it impossible for a browser to read any cookies, which is required in order to safely use server-side sessions with cookies. Make sure that your cookie library also sets the SameSite=strict cookie flag (to prevent CSRF attacks), as well as the secure=true flag (to ensure cookies can only be set over an encrypted connection). Each time a user makes a request to your site, use their session ID (extracted from the cookie they send to you) to retrieve their account details from either a database or a cache (depending on how large your website is)

Answer (score 0):

Redux will store data in the browser memory, it will be lost if you do a full refresh.

If you want to persist your data even after a refresh, you can persist the redux store to the browser session storage https://github.com/ilyagelman/redux-sessionstorage

Otherwise you can save the data you want available in all pages in the session storage without going through redux.

Answer (score 0):

Without actually storing this info in localstoarge there is only one way I can think of achieving this. Your top level component, will re-mount every time the browser refreshes, so in that component's did mount you can fire off a request to get this info from the server and have it stored in your redux store.

Comment: Would prefer not to call out to an API on each route.

Comment: Right, you wont be. The top level component's did mount will only fire on browser refresh, but simply navigating around your app should not re-mount the top level component.

Comment: What about `react-router-dom`s `Redirect`? As this is actually how I stumbled across this, but noticed that refresh had the same effect.

Answer (score -1):

Redux global state gets initialized on page refresh. You need to save userDetails in `localStorage` so it will available across all routes even after refreshing the page.
this is how you can do this:

Set localstorage:

```
 const userDetails = {userName: "foo", pass: "bar"}
 localStorage.setItem('userDetails', JSON.stringify(userDetails));
```

Access userDetails from localStorage:

```
const userDetils = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem( 'userDetails'));
```